# more link to display list of events in fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery

By default fullcalendar displaying all events for particular date,
which is not optimal,I want to display only few events and remaining events should be hidden and more link should display,if i click on *more* remaining events should be displayed.

Comment: which calendar plugin are you talking about?

Comment: Fullcalendar.js   http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

eventLimit

Limits the number of events displayed on a day.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
views: {
    agenda: {
        eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
    }
}});
```